# Why does .get give me PY_VAR0 instead of the string

Tags: python-3.x, class, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Class `Two_players()`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.player1=StringVar()
    self.player2=StringVar()
    self.window1=Tk()
    self.window1.title("Spieler Eingabe")
    self.window1.geometry("500x600")
    self.label_01=Label(self.window1, text="Spieler eingabe",width=25, relief="solid", font=("arial",12,"bold")).pack()
    self.entry_1 = Entry(self.window1,text=self.player1).place(x=170, y=153)
    self.label_03=Label(self.window1, text="Spieler 1 : ", font=("arial",12,"bold")).place(x=80,y=150)
    self.label_04=Label(self.window1, text="Spieler 2 : ", font=("arial",12,"bold")).place(x=80,y=180)
    self.entry_2 = Entry(self.window1,text=self.player2).place(x=170, y=183)
    self.but_01=Button(self.window1,text="wörter eingeben",width=15,bg="black",fg="green", command= lambda :  self.two_players_words()).place(x=200,y=500)
```

Problem is at `label_21` - I want the output to be the `entry_1` but it only shows `py_var0`.

I already tried it with `.get` but that didn't help either:

```
def two_players_words(self):

    window1=Tk()
    window1.title("Wörter Eingabe")
    window1.geometry("500x600")
    label_20=Label(window1, text="Wörter eingabe",width=25, relief="solid", font=("arial",12,"bold")).pack()
    label_21=Label(window1,text=self.player1, font=("arial",12,"bold")).place(x=80,y=150)
    entry_15 = Entry(window1,textvar=word1).place(x=170, y=153)
    label_22=Label(window1, text="{player2} : ", font=("arial",12,"bold")).place(x=80,y=180)
    entry_16 = Entry(window1,textvar=word2).place(x=170, y=183)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `textvariable` parameter rather than text

```
label_21=Label(window1,textvariable=self.player1, font=("arial",12,"bold")).place(x=80,y=150)
```